# Linux Mint 20.2 Live usb booting results in black screen

Tags: linux-mint, boot, grub2, grub, nvidia

I downloaded linux mint 20.2 official iso file and wrote it in to usb flash drive.
I disabled secure boot in bios and booted from USB device.

Than I get GRUB 2.04 menu with these options:

- *Start Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon 64-bit*
- *Start Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon 64-bit (compatibility mode)*
- *OEM install (for manufactures)*
- *Check the integrity of the medium*

No matter what I choose it will result in to irresponsive black screen.

What should I do to make it boot and make functional install ?
Thank you for help

PS: Notebook islenovo S740 with Nvidia graphics card

**EDIT:**

- I tried to force integrated graphics in BIOS. This did not change anything.
- The compatible mode has `nomodeset` as parameter. When I choose it I get same result.
- Yes I did checksum and image is matching published hash
- replacing `nomodeset` with `nouveau.noaccel=1` in compatibility mode does not change anything
- I downloaded and tried to install [Linux mint 20.2 edge](https://linuxmint-user-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/edge.html) with `kernel 5.11` issue still remains

Comment: How long are you waiting? It can take a few minutes for the Live USB to load, and the screen appears black during this period.

Also, Linux Mint supports secure boot out of the box, Please stop disabling secureboot! your USB would work with secureboot enabled!

Comment: @dcom-launch Something around 15 minutes

Comment: This most likely has something to do with the Nvidia card not having the correct drivers to be able to display. I found this forum post from someone with a similar issue, they had to add a a command line parameter to one of the options in GRUB before booting. See https://www.linux.org/threads/linux-mint-wont-install-black-screen.13482/

Comment: Try with the [**boot option**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset` (workaround fro the nvidia graphics).

Comment: @sudodus Thank you for comment. Unfortunetly this did not help (check edit of question)

Comment: What method did you use to write the Linux Mint ISO file to the USB stick?

Comment: I downloaded ISO from official site and wrote it using `rpi-imager`. USB stick is 8gb in size.

Comment: 1. Did you check the download with md5sum or sha256sum? 2. I don't know rpi-imager, but I guess from the name that it is a cloning tool (which should work). - Your laptop is fairly new, and might work better with the newest possible Linux kernel with its hardware drivers. I suggest that you try with [Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS or the even newer version 21.10](https://releases.ubuntu.com/) or the [developing version Jammy](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/429/builds/242368/testcases) to be released as Ubuntu 22.04 LTS in April.

Comment: @sudodus yes I verified image using sha256. What other tool you suggest to write iso to USB flash drive ?

I would like to preferably install mint with cinnamon because it is "just werks" and UI is similar to windows. Choosing other distribution is option if I will not find way hoe to fix this.

Comment: What computer and what operating system is running in the computer, where you want to create the USB boot drive? (RPi and some Linux or PC and some Linux or PC and Windows?) This decides which tool that I will suggest that you use, but if rpi-imager is a cloning tool it should work well with a Mint iso file.

Comment: @sudodus I downloaded and wrote iso on arch linux on thinkpad x390.

Comment: A cloning tool with a GUI that is fairly safe is built into Disks, alias `gnome-disks`. I would not recommend `dd` or some other basic Linux tool because it does what you tell it to do without any final checkpoint, so it is easy to write to the wrong drive and destroy valuable data. An alternative is to use [**`mkusb-min`**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/min) as a safety belt around `dd`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132950/discussion-between-sudodus-and-jan-cerny).

Comment: I added more updates to question

Answer (score 1):

You can use `startup disk creator` to make your stick. It should be ok though. ( Have to do it this way since I cannot comment yet. )

Answer (score 1):

Also had black video issue after installing and rebooting  Mint-21 "Vanessa" on my wife's 15+ year old Hp Pavilion Desktop. Simply went into system BIOS /hardware and changed "graphics" to "onboard" (motherboard).  Rebooted, works great!